# Suppress Error Message Box when file not available

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that open another workbook based on today date. I plan to use task scheduler to auto run but in the case of the external workbook not found, I want my workbook to auto close so it wouldnt stuck there opened. But i encounter error message `Sorry we couldn't open 'D:\Users......."'. Anyway to suppress this error message?

```
Sub DataGrab()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook

    Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("D:\Users\Desktop\Report " & Format(Now, "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xls*", UpdateLinks:=0)
    '
    'my code
    '   
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Quit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to turn off `DisplayAlerts` before the problem might happen, not in the error handling code. By then it's too late. It also makes no sense to turn `DisplayAlerts` back on after you quit the application.

Comment: Dont try to suppress this error, instead check to see if the file exists first using `Dir()`

Comment: @braX: Yes, ideally and if the source is online you may try a MSXML2.XMLHTTP30 status request to check, but on e.g. sharepoint that also recently stopped working, so I need to do it by error handling now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check if the workbook extwbk exists

you can do so with fso.fileexists function

if the file does not exists you can go to errorhandler

please check this image with references I used.

[image]